# is it ok to connect to regular websites (clearnet) with tor but still be anonymous

Tags: clear-net

I am new to tor and tails os and I can't find anything about if it is safe to connect to regular websites, ex go to Reddit.com but still be anonymous (not logging in an account)

Comment: perhaps a helpful site to (play around and) find out, who sees what with or without Tor and https: https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https

Answer (score 1):

It is as safe as using any other browser and internet connection, granted that you live in a country that has not banned tor traffic in general. If you live in a less strict country, say the USA, you can perfectly fine use tor for regular sites like reddit.

Do note on the privacy part however: if you visit regular sites in a systematic order, or log in to your regular user accounts from tor, your anonymity might be at risk, because it theoretically would be possible to map your tor IP together with your regular IP at least for the moment.
If you want more anonymity, do not mix together the two worlds.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to understand what a website sees when you visit. They see your IP and from that they can see where you are physically. Using javascript and cookies, they can actually see and record quite a lot of data about you.

Tor will hide your IP and hide where you are going on the internet and by extension where you are physically. When you add Tor Browser, you can also hide a lot more information about yourself because the goal of Tor Browser is to make you look exactly like every other Tor Browser user. When you visit Reddit, they no longer see **you**, they see **ANONYMOUS TOR USER**. Some websites like Google really don't like that. Their business requires that they gather information about **you** and so they may block you.

This is really what Tor Browser and Tails by extension was designed for.